# Enemy keeps moving right

Tags: python, pygame

So I been trying make my enemy move at the same spot while my player moves the camera but it's not working, when the screen moves my enemy will slowly move from it origanal spot but once its out of my camera veiw it will start glitching. Also when my play collides with a side of a platform my enemy will move the same way as my player but faster e.g.: https://gyazo.com/926207e82cd9849266decd68c08ea84d

A part of my camera movement(Not working)

```
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(-playerman.speed,0)
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.direction = "right"
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")


move = pygame.image.load("WASD.png")


# Playerman
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.idle =[pygame.image.load("player_idel_1.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_2.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_3.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_4.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_5.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_6.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_7.png"),
                            pygame.image.load("player_idel_8.png")
                            ]

        self.idlel = [pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left1.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left2.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left3.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left4.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left5.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left6.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left7.png"),
                         pygame.image.load("Player_idel_left8.png")
                         ]
        self.right = [pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right1.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right2.png"),
                      pygame.image.load("Player_walk_right3.png")]
        
        self.left = [pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left1.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left2.png"),
                     pygame.image.load("Player_walk_left3.png")]

        self.jump1 = [pygame.image.load("Player_jump5.png")]

        
        self.jump2 = [
                     pygame.image.load("Player_rjump1.png")]
        

        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
        self.idle = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.idle]
        self.idlel = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.idlel]
        self.right = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.right]
        self.left = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2, image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.left]
        self.jump1 = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.jump1]
        self.jump2 = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()*2,image.get_height()*2)) for image in self.jump2]
        self.fps = 10
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.anim_index = 0
        self.direction = "idle"
        self.direction = "right"
        self.direction = "left"
        self.dierection = "idleleft"
        self.dierection = "jump1"
        self.dierection = "jump2"
        self.next_frame_time = 0
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
        pygame.draw.rect(self.color,self.rect)
    
    def draw(self):
        if self.direction == "idle":
            image_list = self.idle
        if self.direction == "right":
            image_list = self.right
        if self.direction == "left":
            image_list = self.left
        if self.direction == "idlel":
            image_list = self.idlel
        if self.direction == "jump1":
            image_list = self.jump1
        if self.direction == "jump2":
            image_list = self.jump2
    

         

        # Is it time to show the next animation frame?
        time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if ( time_now > self.next_frame_time ):
            # set the time for the next animation-frame
            inter_frame_delay = 1000 // self.fps   
            self.next_frame_time = time_now + inter_frame_delay  # in the future
            # move the current image to the next (with wrap-around)
            self.anim_index += 1
            if self.anim_index >= len( image_list ):
                self.anim_index = 0
                    
        if self.anim_index >= len(image_list):
            self.anim_index = 0
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        pygame.draw.rect( window, self.color, self.get_rect(), 2 )
        player_image = image_list[self.anim_index]

        player_rect = player_image.get_rect(center = self.get_rect().center)
        player_rect.centerx += 3
        player_rect.centery -= 13
        window.blit(player_image, player_rect)

class Snake:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.path = [x, end]
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.visible = True
        self.no = pygame.image.load("Player_jump5.png")
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.move()
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        window.blit(self.no,self.rect)

    def move(self):
        if self.visible:
            # turn around if the move would go out-of-bounds
            proposed_move = self.x + self.vel
            if ( proposed_move < self.path[0] or proposed_move > self.path[1] ):
                # Move hits a boundary, so we need to turn around
                self.vel = -self.vel
                self.Walking_index = 0
            # now make the correct move
            self.x += self.vel   # add +/- velocity
    def scroll(self,sx,sy):
        self.x += sx
        self.y += sy
        self.path[0] += sx
        self.path[1] += sx


class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.get_rect())


class Rule:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)


# Colors for hitbox
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)

# Drawing Player
playerman = Player(350,445,40,40,white)

#Drawing Platforms
platform1 = Platform(300,-9.1,40,500,green)
platform2 = Platform(330,451,2000,40,green)
platform3 = Platform(2300,-9.1,40,500,green)

# Drawing Rule
rule1 = Rule(340,-9.1,220,500,green)
rule2 = Rule(20000,-9,1,5,green)

snake1 = Snake(100, 110, 64, 64, 300)

# List
platforms = [platform1,platform2,platform3]

rules = [rule1,rule2]

snakes = [snake1]


# draws map
platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
Level = [
"                                         1   1",
"                                         1    ",
"                         1  1        111 1    ",
"                         1  1         1  1    ",
"                         11 1      1  1 11    ",
"                         1  1         1  1    ",
"                         1  1    1    11 1    ",
"           1   1   111   1 11         1  1    ",
"           1   1  11111        1      1          ",]

for iy,row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "1":
            new_platforms = Platform(ix*50,iy*50.2,50,50,(255,255,255))
            platforms.append(new_platforms)
    
            

# Windows color
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    # Drawing the player and other stuff to the screen
    playerman.draw()

    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()
    for Rule in rules:
        Rule.draw()
    for Snake in snakes:
        Snake.draw()

x = 10
y = 10
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y
fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    
            

        


 # part of player screen movment
    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y += playerman.speed

        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(0, +playerman.speed)

    if playerman.y > 410:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y -= playerman.fall
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(0, -playerman.fall)

    # part of side colliding    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            x_change = -7
            for Snake in snakes:
                Snake.scroll(playerman.speed,0)
            
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 7
            for Snake in snakes:
                Snake.scroll(-playerman.speed,0)

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
            x = old_x
           
        # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y

    for Platform in platforms:    
        if playerman.fall > 0 and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if keys[pygame.K_d]:
                playerman.direction = "jump1"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "left":
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    playerman.direction = "jump2"

               

 # direction for player animation and screen movment
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(-playerman.speed,0)
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.direction = "right"

        
    elif keys[pygame.K_a]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed
        if not playerman.isJump:
            playerman.direction = "left"
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(playerman.speed,0)






            
    else:
        if playerman.direction == "left" and playerman.direction == "idlel":
         
            playerman.direction = "idlel"
        else:
            if playerman.direction == "right" and playerman.direction == "idle":
                
                playerman.direction = "idle"


    if playerman.direction == "right" and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        playerman.direction = "jump1"
            
    if playerman.direction == "left":
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            playerman.direction = "jump2"

    
    # sides for player and player screen movment
    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px

    move_right = keys[pygame.K_d]
    move_left = keys[pygame.K_a]
    if move_right: 
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed     # <---
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(-playerman.speed,0)

    if move_left:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed     # <---
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.scroll(playerman.speed,0)

    platform_rect_list = [p.get_rect() for p in platforms] # get_rect()
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    cI = player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list)
    if cI >= 0:
        # undo movement of platforms dependent on the direction and intersection distance
        dx = 0
        if move_right: 
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].left - player_rect.right
        if move_left:
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].right - player_rect.left
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= dx
            Platform.get_rect() # update rectangle
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= dx             # <---
        for Snake in snakes:
            Snake.x -= dx


##############                
  
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
                       
            # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
                py -= playerman.speed
            playerman.fall = 0
            

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

    redrawwindow()
    if playerman.rect.colliderect(rule1.rect):
        window.blit(move,(-40,-100))
    
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's the only issue, but your comparison to test if the Snake can move left in `snake.move()` is subtracting the velocity when it's *negative*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `Snake.move()` doesn't look correct.  It's only considering move in either direction depending on `self.visible`.   Also it's subtracting the `vel` when `vel` is already negative - this has the result of adding the (positive) velocity.

I'm assuming you only want to move the snake if it's visible, and if every you hit the end-points, it turns around.

Possibly re-working this code would help:

```
def move(self):
    if self.visible:
        # turn around if the move would go out-of-bounds
        proposed_move = self.x + self.vel
        if ( proposed_move < self.path[0] or proposed_move > self.path[1] ):
            # Move hits a boundary, so we need to turn around
            self.vel = -self.vel
            self.Walking_index = 0
        # now make the correct move
        self.x += self.vel   # add +/- velocity
```

Comment: Yes thank you it works but do you know why when I touch my platform say the right side, the enemy will keep moving the opposite side? https://gyazo.com/0ec3da620b907dac312f1e2dfc9e4790

Comment: @Windowman - I watched the video, but I don't really understand what you mean.  In the video, the blue creature sprite stops at the blockage.  What do you mean "keep moving the opposite side"?

Comment: I mean like if my player collides with the left side of my platform and keeps pressing the d button form moving right, then my enemy will start moving to the left side.

Comment: @Windowman - Ok, I *suspect* this is because you create the enemy with a fixed screen position, e.g.: `x` (100) and `300`.  Then as the player moves, the screen scrolls, moving the platforms.  So while 100,300 was correct at start, once the platforms move, it's no longer correct.  I think the fix is to turn the enemy around when it collides with a platform, rather than a pre-set screen position.